# Undefined props theme when using local component library in another application, with components using ThemeProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, styled-components

I have two repository `fe` and `craft`, which are the Application and the Component library respectively.

Both repositories can compile fine on their own. However, when I try to use a component through the component library, it will not work if the component itself uses `props.theme` in `styled-components`.

**Main.tsx** from `fe`

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, HeadlineOne } from "handcraft";

const Page = (props: any) => {
  console.log(props.theme);

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => {}}>Sample</Button> // This causes TypeError: Cannot read property 'primary' of undefined.
      <HeadlineOne>Sample</HeadlineOne> // This is fine.
    </>
    );
   };

export default Page.
```

**Button.tsx** from `craft` (NOT OK, access props).

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { Button as BaseButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ButtonText } from "../Typography/Typography";

const StyledButton = styled(BaseButton)`
  text-transform: none;
  width: fit-content;
  min-height: 40px;
  background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.primary}; // Theme props used here.
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.white};

  &:hover {
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.blue500};
  }
`;


...


  return (
    <StyledButton>
      <ButtonText>{children}</ButtonText>
    </StyledButton>
    );
  }
};

export default Button;
```

**Typography.tsx** from `craft` (OK).

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Base = styled.span`
  font-family: Manrope;
  line-height: 1.5;
`;

export const HeadlineOne = styled(Base)`
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 5.875rem;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
`;
```

**preview.js** from `craft`

```
...

addDecorator((story) => (
  <StylesProvider injectFirst>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{story()}</ThemeProvider>
  </StylesProvider>
));
```

**App.tsx** from `fe`

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import theme from "./utils/theme";

const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Page />
  </ThemeProvider>
);

export default App;
```

I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'primary' of undefined` when I try to run the main app.

---

**package.json** from `fe`.

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
```

**package.json** from `craft` (no `dependencies`, only `devDependencies`).

```
},
  "peerDependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    ...
```

---

**The closest I could get to solving this was the solutions here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2379**

I tried both `peerDependencies`, `yarn link` and they do not work. Both repos have the same `theme.js` and both can access the `props.theme` locally perfectly. Both have the same versions of `styled-components`.

How can I import my themed components in an external library to my application which has the same libraries and theme?

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? are you facing this issue on windows?

Comment: Yeah, I'm facing this issue now, wondering if you solved it. I npm linked all these things (and next.js) in the standalone lib and the next.js app, but still getting a blank theme.